# ¿Cómo puedo lograr observar el resultado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero poder divisar el resultado de contenido de GC en la secuencia que introduzca. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
class SeqBase:
    def __init__(self, secstring):
        self.seq = seqstring

    def get_seq(self):
        return self.seq

    def contenido_gc(self):
        """"Regresa el contenido de G y C en BaseSeq"""
        seq = self.get_seq.upper()
        return (seq.count('G') + seq.count('C')) / len(seq)
```

¿cómo puedo lograrlo?
Gracias (:

Comment: A qué te refieres con observar el resultado?? No puedes verlo si usas `print(var.contenido_gc())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemas en el código:

```
def __init__(self, secstring):
    self.seq = seqstring
```

El parámetro es `secstring`, pero dentro usas `seqstring`. Debes usar el mismo nombre en ambos casos.

También hay un error en

```
seq = self.get_seq.upper()
```

Si quieres llamar el método `get_seq`, tienes que usar paréntesis, así:

```
seq = self.get_seq().upper()
```

Para imprimir el resultado, basta con crear un objeto y llamar al método:

```
protseq = "TTLLSETLSEVRGLGTSAQTPPHIKEYIIGIPMSIIHLNVVCRAAMFNAQMQVMVGEAMW" \
          "DWQAMYPRDTFLVMFPIHWPAQNDHPSKQSWDPIYTLFFKNSWFMQPATPRLNKHSVYAW" \
          "YWDRKRVN"
base = SeqBase(protseq)
print(base.contenido_gc())
```

produce:

```
0.0390625
```